# ORA-01756: Quoted string not properly terminated?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a FGA Policy on the sales table for queries done on quantities that are over 100.

This is what I have:

```
 BEGIN
  DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY            
 (
object_schema   =>  'StudentA_1203383',
object_name     =>  'Sales_1203383',
policy_name     =>  'Quantity_Chk_Audit',
audit_condition =>  'Quantity > 100',
audit_column    =>  'Quantity'
);
End;
/
```

I've closed all ''.I don't know whats the issue?

Comment: Issue is this Quantity > 100'

Comment: should only quantity be in quotations?

Comment: Yes space having issue

Comment: I tried  'Quantity' > 100 but still same error

Comment: but I need that for my condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104765/discussion-between-user2127184-and-muhammad-muazzam).